# Initialization of Threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

```
Thread t=new Thread(nr);
```

The parameter `nr` passed while initializing where will be caught in the thread class .

And what is the difference between this and non parametrized initialization like `Thread t= new Thread();` ?

Comment: u can find the best documentation here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

Answer (score 2):

The constructor which takes a Runnable to call `run()` on.

The second constructor will call `run()` on the Thread to start it. The default action is nothing.  This is only useful if you sub-class Thread and override `run()`, but this is generally considered a bad idea as there is poor encapsulation if you do this.

An example of why you shouldn't sub-class Thread.

```
public class Main {
    public String getName() {
        return "Main";
    }

    public String getId() {
        return "My-id";
    }

    public String getState() {
        return "Good";
    }

    public void printMe() {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("name: " + getName() + ", id:" + getId() + ", state:" + getState());
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().printMe();
    }
}
```

prints perhaps surprisingly

```
name: Thread-0, id:11, state:RUNNABLE
```

You may wonder why Thread allows you to sub-class it at all.  The most likely explanation is that Thread was in the original Java 1.0 and at that time they hadn't used interfaces and encapsulation as much as they did in later versions such as Java 1.2 (1998). e.g. the Collections library.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Thread t = new Thread();` there is no implementation of the `Runnable` interface for the thread to run. In `Thread` this is the run function:

```
private Runnable target;
   ...
@Override
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

So if you don't set runnable either using the constructor `target` will be null.

Answer (score 0):

> Two ways to create a thread

```
    Thread thread = new Thread();
    thread.start();
    // This doesn't specify any code for the thread to execute. 
    // It will stop again right away.

    Thread threadname = new Thread("myThread");
    threadname.start();
    // This Allocates a new Thread object.
    // myThread the name of the new thread 


    //There are two ways to create a Thread

    //1) WAY
    //runnable1 and runnable2 are just two different objects of the class 
    //that implements the Runnable interfaces which have that run() method.
    //When you call runnable1.run() you are executing it in the current thread.
    ClassOne runnable1 = new ClassOne();
    ClassTwo runnable2 = new ClassTwo();

    //thread1 and thread2 are the objects of the class Thread. 
    //When you call thread1.start(), it starts a new thread and calls the run()
    //method of runnable1 internally to execute it within that new thread.
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(runnable1);
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(runnable2);
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();

    //2) WAY 
    //Create a subclass of Thread and override the run() method. 
    //The run() method is what is executed by the thread after you call start(). 
    class MyThread extends Thread 
    {
       public void run()
       {
           System.out.println("MyThread running");
       }
    }

    MyThread myThread = new MyThread();
    myThread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

In either way you will create a new thread. In order to perform a task in new Thread you have to override run() method.
There are mainly Three ways to create a new thread:
(1) By implementing Runnable interface in your class.
(2) By extending Thread class.
(3) By using inner class.

Recommended method is the first one by using Runnable interface. Its because if you extend Thread class then you will not be able to extends any other class, but if you use interface you can implement many interfaces and you can extend other class also. 

Your question
1) `Thread t=new Thread(nr);`
Here you are passing a class object which implements runnable interface
2) `Thread t= new Thread();`
This code will not do anything because it does not override run() method. But you can use this code by implementing runnable interface as argument.

Here is code which demonstrates different ways of creating thread.

```
public class ThreadMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Main thread
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

        //Task 1 thread
        //Using runnable
        Thread task1 = new Thread(new Task1());
        task1.start();

        //Task 2 thread
        //By extending Thread class
        Thread task2 = new Task2();
        task2.start();

        //Other way is using inner class
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}

class Task1 implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}

class Task2 extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```